# TCGABiolinks: Error in strsplit(c(colnames(data)), "-") : non-character argument #459

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am working with the new CMI-MBC data and was using TCGABiolink for DEGs identification..
Now at step

```
dataDEGs <- TCGAanalyze_DEA(mat1 = dataFilt[,samplesNT],
+                             mat2 = dataFilt[,samplesTP],
+                             Cond1type = "Primary Tumor",
+                             Cond2type = "Metastatic",
+                             pipeline = "edgeR",
+                             fdr.cut = 0.01 ,
+                             logFC.cut = 1,
+                             method = "glmLRT")
```

I get the error stating `Error in strsplit(c(colnames(data)), "-") : non-character argument.`

I guessed its because of the names of samples MBCProject_0065_T1_RNA_1 and not MBCProject-0065-T1-RNA-1.

Following the logic I tried correcting the sample names by replacing _ with -, but that doesn't help very much.

Any idea what should I do next?

Comment: @akrun I'm sorry the colnames are already in character case, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Can you try after `janitor::clean_names` applied on your dataset

Comment: okay, so here I applied `as.character(dataFilt[,samplesNT])` to the above after using `janitor::clean_names` at console but Its giving me new error `Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [1]`

Comment: I meant, your `dataFilt <- dataFilt %>% clean_names` and then try your function.  Also, the `sampleNT` and `sampleTP` should be updated if these are objects created based on column names

Comment: BTW R doesn’t like column names with ‘-‘.

Comment: @akrun.. clean_names, cleared my whole dataset and converted it into a character type `[1] "x312"    "x0"      "x484"    "x700"    "x1318"   "x4299"   "x596"    "x483"    "x1413"   "x349"    "x319"    "x248"    "x75"    
  [14] "x43`

Comment: ok, can you show a small reproducible example with `dput` so that others can test it